# JavaScript button click even is firing multiple times per click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have a JavaScript/jQuery application in which a Bootstrap Modal window is opened when any of the order cards in the image below are clicked on.

In the Modal HTML, I have a **Start Timer** Button

This timer button is added to the DOM after the DOM has already been loaded.  SO I use this code below to attach a click event to the button after DOM loaded...

```
// Handle Timer Start Button click event
$(document).on('click', '.start-job-btn', function(e) {

    console.log('start timer');
    alert('start timer');

    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default
    return false;

});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-order-id="5508" data-order-item-id="158" class="btn btn-primary start-job-btn">Start Job</a>
```

---

**The Problem**

When I click the start button I get my alert and console logger ran 3-6 times each button click!

I cannot figure out why this would happen as it doesn't happen in any other sections of the app.  Just this button which has the code shown above.

It's hard to setup a demo app as the project is over 10k lines and would be hard to get it all up but based on this info does anyone have any ideas?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the code where you run the js in your snippet. Is that modal coming from ajax?

Comment: Are you running that code to bind the handler every time you add a button to the DOM? You should only run it once, when the DOM is first loaded.

Comment: @Barmar I just realized that each modal I open and click the button, it fires the event the number of modals I have opened on that page load.  For example on my 3rd modal being opened, it will fire event 3 times.  The way the app is structured, each column has it;s own codebase.  I would be best to somehow terminate the click even when the modal is closed so when the next modal is opened, it will work correctly

Comment: It looks like jQuery's `off()` is my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the code every time you create a modal, so all the buttons are getting multiple click handlers -- one for each modal.

You should either take that code out of the code that creates modals, so you only run it once. Or you should change it so that it only binds to the buttons in that modal:

```
this_modal.on("click", ".start-job-btn", function() {
    ...
});
```

where `this_modal` is a reference to the current modal being created.

Comment: what would happen if he opens the same modal more than once?

Comment: This code should be run when creating the modal, not when opening it.

Comment: I get what you're saying.  I basically have an object for each of my board columsn but I also have a base object so I should try putting this into the base object.  The modal open functionality is in the individual baord objects so this looks like a good idea thanks

Comment: true. but OP did not show all the code. maybe he is using only one modal with dynamic content added to the body of it.

Comment: For example I have a function that handles posting comments on all the modals and since all the modals have this feature it is in my base object.  I think I can plug right in with this.  This button is only on 1 of about 20 modals but I don't think that will cause any issue if the button element is missing on the other modals?

Comment: Correct. If there are no elements matching the selector, this will have no visible effect (there's a small performance impact).

Comment: @taxicala I beleive it is a seperite modal created when each click even fires even though it does generate new content for each modal I think it generates and destroys the modals but i could be wrong, this project is huge so i've forgotten how some parts are over time.  SInce the click even isnt destroyed on modal close, perhaps it does recycle the same modal window

Comment: BTW this worked!  Also thankful as it is making me reconsider lots of other parts of the app to reduce size and repetition

Answer (score 1):

As per your latest comment, i see two possible solutions here.
first, put your previous code only in the page that will load the modals. There is no need to bind the event with every call. You will be binding a new function to the same event each time you open a modal.

And you mentioned jquery off method, that would also work:

```
$(document).off('click', '.start-job-btn');
$(document).on('click', '.start-job-btn', function(e) {
    console.log('start timer');
    alert('start timer');
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I liked the `off()` method idea at first but I tested it and it just didnt work right for some reason so i'm gonna try Barmar's solution now